# QML change Button icon size

Tags: qt, qml

How can I change the size of a Button icon?
If i set icon.height and icon.width it gives me this error:

*QML IconLabel: Binding loop detected for property "icon"*

```
    Button {
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height * 0.2
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
        Layout.row: 4
        Layout.column: 0
        Layout.columnSpan: 3
        icon.source: "qrc:/media/dazn.png"
        icon.height: height
        icon.width: width
    }
```

Comment: You should indeed not bind to `height` and `width`, since these properties are indirectly calculated from the icon size plus the padding, leading to the mentioned binding loop. Not sure about your exact intentions, but you could bind to `Layout.preferredHeight`

Comment: Thank you, post the comment as answer so I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed not bind to `height` and `width`, since these properties are indirectly calculated from the icon size plus the padding, leading to the mentioned binding loop. Not sure about your exact intentions, but you could bind to `Layout.preferredHeight` and `Layout.preferredWidth`

```
Button {
    Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height * 0.2
    Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
    Layout.row: 4
    Layout.column: 0
    Layout.columnSpan: 3
    icon.source: "qrc:/media/dazn.png"
    icon.height: Layout.preferredHeight
    icon.width: Layout.preferredWidth
}
```

It seems the icon is still constrained by some limits (inside `IconLabel`), however it will get as big as allowed.

Comment: What if the button isn’t in a layout? Could you still bind to something like the implicitHeight?

Comment: Using implicitHeight/Width will most probably also end up in a binding loop since the implicit size of the contentItem is taken into account. In that case I think you should use static values or a binding to outside the button (like the parent.height in the question)